# Image TapGestureRecognizer not firing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I dont really understand why this image TapGestureRecognizer not firing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MainMenu">   

    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"
                Android="0, 0, 0, 0"
                WinPhone="0, 0, 0, 0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid>

            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <BoxView BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                <Image Source="itemIcon1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Label Text = "Cpyname" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>


                <Grid Grid.Row="1">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width ="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width ="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width ="200"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <StackLayout  HeightRequest="80" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>



                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="110" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image x:Name="ImgRepairSvc" Source="M1.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="110" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source="M2.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        </StackLayout>


                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here the code:

```
1) XAML :

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="110" Orientation="Vertical">
   <Image x:Name="ImgSvc" Source="M1.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>  
</StackLayout>


2) Code behind the XAML:

public MainMenu 
{           
     InitializeComponent ();            
     SetUp();

}


 void SetUp()
 {

    ImgSvc.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
    {
       Command = new Command(TapCallback)

    });

  }


  private void TapCallback()
  {
     DisplayAlert("Tap", "This is image Tap", "Ok");

  }
```

Compiling is successful on Emulator (Droid), but when use mouse to click the image, there is no displayAlert.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you put breakpoint inside `TapCallback` and didn't stop on it or just you're not able to see alert?

Comment: When clicking the image in emulator , nothing happened. Even I have set breakpoint in TapCallback.  Is tap same as click when test on emulator?

Comment: Please show the rest of your layout, you probably have something overlapping your image. Give your elements a backgroundcolor and/or set the `InputTransparent` property to true where you can

Comment: @Gerald Please see the update of the entire Page.

Comment: do you have a `public ICommand TapCommand {` that returns your Command object?

Comment: @GregHNZ  The above code is all I have. Please advise how to implement IComand.

Comment: This page, near the bottom, under "Using ICommand", has something that looks similar to what you're doing. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/  - when I look at your code, all I see is "When the user taps, create a new Command object.  But I don't see anything that says "execute TapCommand" or "give the framework a handle on my new command object, so it can" - maybe add the binding in the XAML, and implement the interface similar to what's on that page?

Comment: @ GregHNZ I m not using MVVM. I follow this site: http://mobilecafe.lexiconsystemsinc.com/xamarin-forms/id-tap-that-clickable-images-with-gesturerecognizer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most of why this is not working correctly is the chaotic structure of all the `Grid` and `StackLayout` controls you're using. You have a grid with a column that has a `Width` set to 40. In that column you're adding a `Grid` that has a column which has a `Width` of 200 and an `Image` that is 110 wide. You can see it in this image:

[image]

When I click on the `Image` (red) the `TapGestureRecognizer` only triggers when you click the left part of the image that is within the Fuchsia colored `Grid` element. Everything outside that is being rendered outside the parent of the `Image` won't trigger the `TapGestureRecognizer`.

**My advice is to clean up your XAML because I can't imagine you're creating a layout that needs this kind of complexity with all the nested `StackLayout` and `Grid` controls.**

Here's the code with a BackgroundColor set to each element in case you want to see for yourself.

```
 <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"
                Android="0, 0, 0, 0"
                WinPhone="0, 0, 0, 0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
                <Image BackgroundColor="Olive" Source="itemIcon1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Label BackgroundColor="Gray" Text = "Cpyname" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Teal">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Fuchsia">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Lime" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="80" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Maroon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="110" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image x:Name="ImgRepairSvc" BackgroundColor="Red" Source="M1.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Purple" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="110" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source="M2.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: @Both : Steven and Gerald, Thanks. Your advise works. I clean up the layout and Try. It works.